# Rendering raw email mesages in the browser

Tags: javascript, email, puppeteer, render

How do I render raw email messages in a browser?

I'm trying to use puppeteer to take screenshots of email messages but loading the whole message does not look right at all:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An email message has many parts (like From, To, Attachments, etc) as it turns out.

I needed to parse the raw mail message which I did using [mailparser](https://nodemailer.com/extras/mailparser/).

```
import { simpleParser } from 'mailparser';

const parsed = await simpleParser(emailMessage);

// call screenshot service with `parsed.html` or `parsed.textAsHtml`
```

`mailparser` is brilliant as it gives you everything you could want from a message including:

- headers
- subject
- from
- to
- cc
- bcc
- date
- inReplyTo
- reply-to
- messageId
- references
- html
- text
- textAsHtml
- attachments